# Keep column order at DataFrame creation

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to keep the columns in the order they were defined with `pd.DataFrame`. In the example below, `df.info` shows that *GroupId* is the first column and `print` also prints *GroupId*.
I'm using Python version 3.6.3

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : np.random.randint(1,100,10), 
                       'GroupId' : np.random.randint(1,5,10) })
df.info()
print(df.iloc[:,0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), as below. Note that the OrderedDict object takes a list of tuples as an input.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([('Id', np.random.randint(1,100,10)), 
                               ('GroupId', np.random.randint(1,5,10))]))

#    Id  GroupId
# 0  37        4
# 1  10        2
# 2  42        1
# 3  97        2
# 4   6        4
# 5  59        2
# 6  12        2
# 7  69        1
# 8  79        1
# 9  17        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using python-3.6+ where dictionaries are ordered, this just isn't possible with a (standard) dictionary. You will need to `zip` your items together and pass a list of tuples:

```
np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)
b = np.random.randint(1, 5, 10)
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b)), columns=['Id', 'GroupId'])
```

Or,

```
data = [a, b]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*data)), columns=['Id', 'GroupId']))
```

```
df
   Id  GroupId
0  45        3
1  48        1
2  65        1
3  68        1
4  68        3
5  10        2
6  84        3
7  22        4
8  37        4
9  88        3
```